# Permissions.askAsync not working as expected

Tags: react-native, push-notification, permissions, expo

I am having an issue with Permissions.askAsync for notifications.

```
const status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
```

When notification status is "undetermined" using Permissions.askAsync I expect to be presented with prompt dialog telling user to turn on notifications in order to continue. But, when I get status of the notifications with Permissions.getAsync, if it's not "granted" I use Permissions.askAsync but nothing is happening(not showing the dialog for notifications)

**Environment below:**

```
Target: iOS
Expo CLI 3.8.0 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.6
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 12.13.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
npm: 6.12.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ^35.0.0 => 35.0.1
react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8
react-navigation: ^3.11.0 => 3.12.1
npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 3.8.0
```

**Sample below:**

```
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions"

componentDidMount(){
   this.checkPushNotificationState()
}

checkPushNotificationState = async () => {

  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  )

  if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
    const status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    statusNotifications = status.status
  }
}
```

Comment: Had you previously not granted permission? i.e. said no when requested? I think ios remembers that and won't allow the request again unless you go to your app settings and explicitly enable it.

Comment: Yes, I have not granted permission at first and would like to show that dialog after that. Is it not possible? In that case only solution is for user to manually allow notifications from iPhone settings("Notifications" and allow it from there)?

Comment: From what I remember that is the catch - we ran into the same issue with our app. But I stand to be corrected, will do some digging my side as well.

Comment: Yeah so here is a conversation on the expo forum about it: https://forums.expo.io/t/asking-for-permissions-again-when-denied-the-first-time/10218/2. Not sure how relevant it is because the last answer was in May 2018, but there isn't much else out there from what I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 9):

use app-setting link to open setting for manual permission because ios do not allow us to give permission from prompt if user reject permission

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
```

like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Linking, Alert } from "react-native";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPushNotificationState();
  }

  checkPushNotificationState = async () => {
    let { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );

    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      existingStatus = status.status;
    }
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      Alert.alert(
        "No Notification Permission",
        "please goto setting and on notification permission manual",
        [
          { text: "cancel", onPress: () => console.log("cancel") },
          { text: "Allow", onPress: () => Linking.openURL("app-settings:") },
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      return;
    }
  };
```

**Note:** you should use double permission for [The Right Way to Ask Users for Mobile Permissions](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/)
[image]