# EXPO. Notifications do not popup

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

`"expo": "^39.0.0"` / Library - expo-notifications.

Since moving to the new API, I have been facing various problems. I fixed problems with the icon, with receiving a notification in apk, with  handlers, and now I could not find an answer to this question.

I have 3 phones ***Samsung Galaxy S9+*** with `Android 10`, ***Xiaomi Redmi 4x*** with `Android 7.12 N2G47H MIUI 10 Global 9.6.27` and ***Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 Global*** `Android 7.0 nrd90m MIUI global 11.0.2`.

Samsung Galaxy S9+. With my current config i receive notification
excellent as it should be:

- Vibration +
- Sound +
- Popup when notification comes +

**All this come from the box, i do not need to ask permissions or something like that.**

Xiaomi Redmi 4x and Xiaomi Redmi Note 4.
With my current config i have problems:

- Vibration - **do not work both in both published and apk(standalone) versions**
- Sound +
- Popup when notification comes +

**AND THE MAIN PROBLEM: All this DO NOT come from the box, I need to manually give permission for notifications to pop up, sound, etc.**

My app.json :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "qwert",
    "slug": "qwert",
    "version": "1.1.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/logo1024.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/images/splashScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#f1f0f0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.qwert.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./src/assets/images/VIAicon96.png",
      "color": "#8edcd5",
      "androidMode": "collapse"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

My permissions/configs:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});

export const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
  let token;
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS,
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    console.log('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  return token;
};
```

Also, place where use all this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNotification = async () => {
      await getPermitsAndIntegrateIntoApp(store);  // works great
    };
    const setPersistDataToStore = async () => {
      const EXPO_PUSH_TOKEN = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
      const qwertyyy = await getConfig(Constants.deviceId, EXPO_PUSH_TOKEN);
      store.setQwerrt(config.destinations);
    };
    setPersistDataToStore();

    Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(handleNotification);

    return () => Notifications.removeAllNotificationListeners();
  }, [store]);
```

On all 3 phones I have a logic for handling notifications ( send request, updates store, and updates screen on my app). It works correct.

**How to automatically configure the permission to show push notifications? How to enable vibration on Xiaomi?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an answers.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8556  tells us that [image]
And that
[Permissions.askAsync not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980039/permissions-askasync-not-working-as-expected)  tells us how to let user set permissions to notifications.

And i still do not know why Xiaomi do not vibrate......

Answer (score 0):

I have Xiaomi Redmi 6A, and with default configuration from examples in Expo documentation I received only vibration on notification. I have to manually turn on pop up (floating) and sound for default channel. Only after that notifications began to work as expected.


[image]
[image]