# App notification setting access in EXPO sdk39

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, settings

Problem started when i realize that Permissions.askAsync not working as expected.

I find [Permissions.askAsync not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980039/permissions-askasync-not-working-as-expected/64652397#64652397)  and it`s cool solution for ios, but i need it for android! So, i add some extra code for this:

```
Alert.alert(
        'No Notification Permission',
        'please go to settings and enable notifications permissions manually',
        [
          { text: 'cancel', onPress: () => console.log('cancel') },
          {
            text: 'Allow',
            onPress: async () => {
              if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
                  IntentLauncher.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS,
                  {
                    data: `package:${Application.applicationId}`,
                  }
                );
              }
              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
              }
            },
          },
        ],
        { cancelable: false },
      );
```

UPD. construction below works great, but i want to access directly to the APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS.

```
onPress={() => {
            IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
              IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
              {
                data: `package:${Application.applicationId}`,
              }
            );
          }}
```

Related issue in expo forums https://forums.expo.io/t/opening-device-settings-on-android-using-linking/2059/14

I try to access to the APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS but for some reason i'm getting error like ***"The app wasn't found in the list of installed apps".*** Tried it on published project and on standalone (apk) and got the same result. Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a bit late, but the suggested answer didn't work for me. This is what worked on my device using **Android Version 29**:

```
const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
    ? Constants.manifest.android.package
    : 'host.exp.exponent';

IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
    IntentLauncher.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS,
    {
        extra: { 'android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE': pkg }
    },
);
```

TL;DR: The key change here being `android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE` as the `extra` key name.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
const pkg = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel
        ? Constants.manifest.android.package // When published, considered as using standalone build
        : 'host.exp.exponent'; // In expo client mode

onPress: () => {
              if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
                  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
                    IntentLauncher.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS,
                    {
                      data: `package:${pkg}`,
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
                    IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    {
                      data: `package:${pkg}`,
                    },
                  );
                }
              }
              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
              }
            },
```

Solution description: https://forums.expo.io/t/api-to-open-app-settings/5290/18